Doubts over the proof of Thomson's theorem by M.C.N.Fiolhais et al
I have some doubts with the following proof: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0375960116303619.
The paper shows a variational proof of thomson's theorem in electrostatics.
I am unable to comprehend the passage from formula $(8)$ to formula $(9)$: when you do the variation, for example, you should come up with a term $\alpha \cdot \Delta(\delta \Phi)$ (by varying $\alpha \cdot \Delta \Phi$ and ignoring $\alpha$, as the paper says) inside the volume integral, and by using Green's theorem, you should come up with the volume integral of $\delta \Phi \cdot \Delta \alpha + \operatorname{div}(\alpha \cdot \operatorname{grad}(\Phi)-\Phi \cdot \operatorname{grad}(\alpha))$ (I'm talking just about that term).
In formula $(9)$ the volume integral of $\operatorname{div}(\alpha \cdot \operatorname{grad}(\Phi)-\Phi \cdot \operatorname{grad}(\alpha))$ disappears. Why is so? Are they assuming boundary conditions over $\alpha$ (and $\beta$) or am I not seeing something more, is it lecit to impose $\alpha=0$ and $\operatorname{grad}(\alpha)=0$ over the boundary? (it seems unjustified to me). Thanks in advance for any answer you'll provide to me!

The cited article is behind a pay-wall for me.
